# DIfficulty mocking core data objects

Tags: unit-testing, ios5

I am running unit testing for a model file which uses core data. The test target builds successfully, but i am seeing the following errors :

error: testThatDistinguishedFolderTypeForTheAccountExists (FolderDALTests) failed: +entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'Folder' in this model.

error: testThatFindByExchageAccountReturnsFolders (FolderDALTests) failed: +entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'ExchangeAccount' in this model.

However, i feel that the problem is caused due to the "setup" method, where the NSManagedObjectModel is not created using merging all the models found in bundles.

```
-(void)testThatDistinguishedFolderTypeForTheAccountExists
 {
   Folder *inbox = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Folder" 
   inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
   inbox.distinguishedFolderType = @"inbox";
   ExchangeAccount *account = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ExchangeAccount" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
   id<FolderProtocol> folder = [FolderDAL findWithAccount:account DistinguishedFolderType:@"inbox" withManagedContext:self.context];

STAssertTrue([folder.folderDistinguishedFolderType isEqualToString:@"inbox"], @"Unable to find the folder with the given distinguished type");
```

}

And the other method is :

```
- (void)testThatFindByExchageAccountReturnsFolders
  {
      ExchangeAccount *account = [NSEntityDescription          insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ExchangeAccount" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];

     Folder *inbox = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Folder"     inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
     inbox.displayName = @"Inbox";
     inbox.exchangeAccount = account;

     Folder *calendars = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Folder" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
     calendars.displayName = @"Calendars";
     calendars.exchangeAccount = account;

     NSArray *folders = [FolderDAL findByExchangeAccount:account withContext:self.context];

     STAssertTrue([folders count] > 0, @"No folders were returned");
  }
```

The setup method is :

```
- (void)setUp
{
  [super setUp];

  NSManagedObjectModel *objectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSBundle mainBundle]]];
  NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *storeCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:objectModel];
  STAssertTrue([storeCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSInMemoryStoreType configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:NULL] ? YES : NO, @"Should be able to add in-memory store");
  self.context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
  self.context.persistentStoreCoordinator = storeCoordinator;
```

}

Here, "Folder" and "ExchangeAccount" are the core data entities. And their corresponding DAL(Data Access Layer) files have some of their business logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to add the unit test as a target to the schema.

Comment: PS: you're not mocking anything. You should edit your question title.